# Creating collections in solr4.4 cloud with different schemas

Tags: solrcloud

How can I create collections in solr4.4 cloud with different schema.

I want to create collection in solr4.4 cloud having two shard. However each collection should have schema of its own i.e each collection have different schema

Answer (score 2):

you would have to upload two configs to zookeeper for each schema, and then make two collection apis call like:

```
curl -v "http://localhost:8080/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=collection1&numShards=2&collection.configName=collection1"
```

and

```
curl -v "http://localhost:8080/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=collection2&numShards=2&collection.configName=collection2"
```